# Prolog : append to list

Tags: list, prolog, append, max, predicate

I have facts like that :
student(stud01, 'Programming 1', 90).
student(stud01, 'Math 1', 78).
student(stud01, 'Statistics 1', 94).
student(stud01, 'Electronics 1', 81).
student(stud01, 'Management', 66).
student(stud01, 'English', 83).

i want to build a predict that take the student id and and put all its grade in list
and after that take the max grade

i try this :
stuGrade(ID,List):-
stuGrade([],ID,List).

stuGrade(TmpList,ID,List):-
student(ID,Course,Grade),
not(mem([ID],TmpList)), !,
append_List([Grade],TmpList,NewTmpList),
stuGrade(List,ID,NewTmpList).

stuGrade(List,ID,List).

maxStudentGrade(ID,Max):-
stuGrade(ID,L),
max(L,Max).

but the problem that after using ?-trace. i see that the output list containing only the first grade (90) how can i slove this problem

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that you begin with `?- stuGrade(stu01, List).`

Then you will get the first student entry at least. And you say there is some issue after that.

So, a simple way to check is to test by using the first part of the query, such that,

```
?- ID = stu01, TmpList = [],
   student(ID,Course,Grade),
   not(mem([ID],TmpList)), !.
```

When you find its result is `false`, stop and check the last predicate.

#### Using break points

`trace/0` and `nodebug/0` are nice tools.

You may want to check issues by like the following,

```
stuGrade(TmpList, ID, List) :-
  student(ID, Course, Grade),
  trace,  % <------------------ Put a break point here.
  not(mem([ID], TmpList)),
  nodebug, % <----------------- Here, stop tracing.
  !,
  append_List([Grade], TmpList, NewTmpList),
  stuGrade(List, ID, NewTmpList).
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

And you code...

```
stuGrade(ID,List):- stuGrade([],ID,List).

stuGrade(TmpList, ID, List):-
  student(ID, Course, Grade),
  not(mem([ID], TmpList)),
  !, 
  append_List([Grade], TmpList, NewTmpList),
  stuGrade(List, ID, NewTmpList).

stuGrade(List,ID,List).
```

Not bad. But, consider the first clause of `stuGrade/3`.

When you get a `Grade`, it's prepended to `TmpList` and you get `NewTmpList`. But at the next line, the newly built list is put as the third argument, as you know that it's for the final returned `List`.

It cannot be that. The first parameter of `stuGrade/3`, `TmpList`, is the accumulating parameter. Then `NewTmpList` might be placed as the first argument of the recursive query, such that `stuGrade(NewTmpList, ID, List)`.

Comment: when i try this stuGrade(NewTmpList,ID,List).
no output appear like it is an infinte loop

Comment: Yes, it's another issue. Then you have to figure out the base case of recursion, and it's a trivial task.